# function call in python

Tags: python

I wrote a function and I try to call it but it gives me error

```
  NameError: name 'fun' is not defined
```

Example:

```
(p1,p2) = fun(price1,price2)

def fun(price1,price2):
  do something
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to define functions before you can call them.  Function definitions in Python are executable statements like any other, and are executed in the order they occur in the source file.  Move your `def fun` block up ahead of the place where you call it.

Answer (score 3):

In a standalone script like this, you'll have to define the function before you call it. So just change it to:

```
def fun(price1,price2):
    do something

(p1,p2) = fun(price1,price2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like the interpreter is running the the line of code calling the function before it is defining the function.  You need to switch them around, or else wrap the function call code itself in a function like `main()` and call that after everything is defined.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a standalone script, then you need to call `fun` after you have defined it.

```
def fun(price1,price2):
  do something

(p1,p2) = fun(price1,price2)
```